# Delayed_jobs - clear memory between jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

Is there a way to force DJ to "clean" the memory between jobs? its seems that currently its just accumulates memory until it exceeds the amount we gave him.

Im also working on spotting the area on the code which eats most of the memory but still would love to have the option on cleaning the memory between jobs.

using collectiveidea-delayed_job - 2.0.5

Comment: what version of delayed job / ruby are you using ?

Comment: collectiveidea-delayed_job - 2.0.5

Comment: did you try to call `GC.start` between jobs ?

Comment: @Coren I tried calling that at the end of my memory-heavy methods and it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you tried using bleak_house (https://github.com/evan/bleak_house) or oink (https://github.com/noahd1/oink) to find the source of the memory that is not being collected by `GC`?

Comment: You could restart the process when memory limit is reached, for example you can use god, see: https://github.com/blog/229-dj-god